# Scrapy bot and shell return different results with same xpath query. Why?

Tags: xpath, scrapy, scrapy-shell

When I execute the same xpath query in a scrapy bot and in the scrapy shell, I'm getting different results.

Note: I'm merely trying to learn scrapy and so modifying some of the tutorial code. Please go slowly with me.

The query:

```
xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href')
```

The bot:

```
import scrapy

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["lib-web.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)


    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.xpath('p/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

DmozItem:

```
import scrapy

class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
```

What I want are just the links to the state public library pages (see web page).

Here's what the shell shows (which is exactly what I want):

```
Admin$ scrapy shell http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries
...snip...
In [1]: response.selector.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href')
Out[1]: 
[<Selector xpath='//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href' data=u'/united-states/public-libraries/alabama/'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href' data=u'/united-states/public-libraries/alaska/'>,
...snip. for brevity...
 <Selector xpath='//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href' data=u'/united-states/public-libraries/wisconsi'>,
 <Selector xpath='//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href' data=u'/united-states/public-libraries/wyoming/'>]
```

When the spider runs that same query, I get additional href selections that I don't want.

A few examples:

```
2015-11-10 13:27:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/alabama/>
{'desc': [], 'link': [u'http://www.dirbuzz.com'], 'title': [u'DirBuzz.com']}
2015-11-10 13:27:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/alabama/>
{'desc': [], 'link': [u'http://www.dirville.com'], 'title': [u'DirVille']}
2015-11-10 13:27:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/alabama/>
{'desc': [], 'link': [u'http://www.duddoo.com'], 'title': [u'Duddoo.net']}
```

As far as I can tell, many of the elements/links returned by the bot **don't fit** the xpath selector. How is that happening? Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `parse` function. This line `response.xpath('//div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href')` will give you the list of all the links to the state libraries that you want. Now you're iterating over all the scraped links and following the links using this line `yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)`. Then your bot is calling back the function `parse_dir_contents`. In this function, your bot is selecting all the elements that are present in the xpath `//ul/li`. So the link you see as the output is actually present in the followed link's page and not the `start_url's` page. That's why there is a difference between the shell output and spider's output. The shell output only shows the links from the url that you have passed to it. You can crosscheck your results by visiting the url `http://www.lib-web.org/united-states/public-libraries/alabama/` and check if it contains this url `http://www.dirbuzz.com`.

Comment: Yes. That's it! I feel dumb now. Noob mistake. Thanks so much!